# How to disable popping up "Convert File" dialog while opening .rtf documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

When I trying to open a Rich Text Format document (`*.rtf`) the following dialog is appearing:

[image]

How to open `*.rtf` files without showing this "Convert File" dialog?

*Version: Microsoft Word 2016.*

**Update:**
I found the same question on the `stackoverflow.com`. But this topic is related to case when document is opening from the c# application:

[How to open a RTF file with C# without showing the Microsoft Word “Convert File” dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5016484/6630084)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is `Confirm file format conversion on open` checkbox in the `Word Options` dialog, on 'Advanced` tab.  If you want Word to select the correct converter automatically and open the document, click to clear this check box.

[image]

See an additional information here: [The ConfirmConversions property in Macro changes the "Confirm Conversion at Open" option in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-confirmconversions-property-in-macro-changes-the-confirm-conversion-at-open-option-in-word-6f16c1db-4cb8-2727-dc4f-fdf6ef112ff5)

Comment: This only means that Word selects automatically the converter that it uses to open the document, so the file conversion is done without notification. It does not explain why conversion was required in the first place.

Comment: I would ask "Why this dialog does appear?" Because of the Word does not make any changes in the document after I pressed `OK` in this dialog and the file created in the same MS Word, i.e the document is well formed too. One example of _**mystical**_ ways of working software of Microsoft... :)

Comment: My experience with Word files is that this dialog is extremely rare and usually pertains to very old files of old format. I don't know why it happens on your computer, but it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @harrymc: As I described above this happens on a new created file on the same computer where this file is created. And this happens not only one computer. Windows 10 and the Microsoft Office are up to date.

Comment: Are you installing some add-ons? See if it happens with new files in safe mode: `winword /safe`.

Answer (score 1):

Word should open a real RTF document without asking any question.

This dialog appears when the file being opened cannot be automatically
identified by Word as having a format it can understand, so it asks for
your help.

It seems that your RTF file or files are badly constructed.

You may test this by saving the file, still in RTF format, then open the
new file. If the dialog appears again, Office may be malfunctioning
and needs to be repaired. If the dialog no longer appears, then the
original file is malformed.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I've already thought about that. Therefore, I did the following. Opened the Word and selected _“Blank Document”_. Added some formatted lines. File ► Save as… ► Entered a file name (`12345`). In the “Save as type:” field selected `Rich Text Format (*.rtf)` and I pressed the `Save` button. Exit from the Word and double click on the `12345.rtf` file. The Word is launched and shown me the same `Convert File` dialog. So unfortunately, this is not the case - document is well formed. BTW, after opening the document the Word title shows `12345.rtf [Compatibility Mode]`.